# uploading video files directly to aws s3 using node.js without storing it in the server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I am writing a mobile application which uploads videos to the server which runs in Heroku PaaS. I am using 'multer ' middleware to upload video files.  Here the problem i face is that multer cannot be used in Heroku PaaS since it creates folder in the server. I am planning to use Amazon S3 to store my files and keep the database of the files in MongoDB. But is there any way to upload files directly to AWS S3 from post request and store the file name in our database without storing the files in the temp directory in the server. Please advice me in this regard.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). Your question is a bit too broad seeking general advice, and not an answer to a concrete programming question. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too, despite its harsh title.

Answer (score 0):

S3 can be uploaded directly to from your clients, without going through your servers. You can have your server issue signed upload credentials or [Post Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html) and that way your server never has to handle the bandwidth of receiving and sending the files.